# Error to up centos docker container with cvs

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos7, cvs

I need a centos7 machine with cvs installed to run some tests. So I created a dockerfile that provides this container for me. But when I run this container, the following error occurs: standard_init_linux.go: 211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory". Anyone have any idea how to fix this error?

## Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER Glauber Oliveira <glauberqo@gmail.com>
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN yum update -y && yum install cvs xinetd -y
RUN useradd cvs && useradd -p cvsgit migration
RUN mkdir /opt/cvsroot && cvs -d /opt/cvsroot init
RUN chown -R :cvs /opt/cvsroot && chmod -R g+ws /opt/cvsroot
RUN touch /opt/cvsroot/CVSROOT/passwd && echo "migration:cvsgit" >> /opt/cvsroot/CVSROOT/passwd
COPY files/cvspserver /etc/xinetd.d/
ADD files/run.sh /
RUN chmod +x run.sh
RUN systemctl enable xinetd.service
RUN usermod -a -G cvs migration
EXPOSE 2401
CMD [ "/run.sh", "run" ]
```

## run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#systemctl enable xinetd.service
systemctl start xinetd.service
```

Comment: While it isn't your immediate problem, you should know that `systemctl` basically doesn't work in Docker.  If it doesn't fail outright, your `run.sh` will just cause the container to exit immediately without actually starting anything.  You need to run the daemon as a foreground process as the main container `CMD`.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the line endings which are Windows style (`CR LF`) instead of Unix (`LF`). If you run the command script `run.sh` directly on Unix you will get the following error:

```
-bash: ./run.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Convert the EOLs in the script using a text editor or the dos2unix utility.